# File Not Found for File with Turkish Characters

Tags: java, file, io

I have a problem with using File and FileInputStream.  I have a web application that allows users to attach files (that I store on the server filesystem) and then I stream them back when they want to download them.

A file has been attached that has Turkish characters and spaces in the name.  The error has the same name as the file on the Linux file system but I get a: java.io.FileNotFoundException, No such file or directory.  The file was upload correctly and renamed to its current name successfully as part of the attaching process.  Files without the Turkish character work fine.

I know it sounds like it is the Turkish character but then why was this able to be renamed to a Turkish name in the first place.

This is for a Customer (in Turkey) but I have screen shots showing the error message and directory of the file system and the names seem to match.

Does anyone know what the problem could be.

Thanks
Paul

EDIT:

The copy process involves creating a new File object (attachment object has details of what filename will be used)

```
new File(attachmentDir + SEPARATOR + attachment.getID()+(StringUtils.isBlank(attachment.getIssueKey())?"":"_"+attachment.getFileName()));
```

And then moving from temporary directory with

```
file.renameTo(attachmentFile);
```

Comment: Show the code you use to generate the file name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find answer so fell back to filtering the directory listing by the unique number that was appended to the front of each file name.  Not ideal but a work around at least.